# Pass HTML into Mat Dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to pass HTML into my Mat Dialog code as the message parameter. So I have the following but am not sure how I can pass HTML into it.

```
  openAlertDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AlertDialogComponent,{
      data:{
        message: '<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>',
        buttonText: {
          cancel: 'Done'
        }
      },
    });
  }
```

I want to add HTML in the `message`

I have a stackblitz of the code here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-kchzml?file=app/app.component.ts

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can display your HTML message using **innerHTML** attribute. Change it to below.

```
<mat-dialog-content [innerHTML]="message">
</mat-dialog-content>
```

Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-eviidy?file=app%2Falert-dialog%2Falert-dialog.component.html)