# ViewChild and ContentChildren are undefined in Angular Material Dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, jasmine

I have a Angular Material Dialog Component that takes Inputs and uses them in header and footer of modal. I want to pass some html elements in modal's body section from a component.

dashboard.component.html displays a 'show/hide columns' button.

**dashboard.component.html**

```html
<app-modal [title]="title" [btnText]="text'>
   <section #template>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" *ngIf="!showForm && viewParams.length > 0 && cn_hostname_index >= 0">
      <mat-label>Search Columns</mat-label>
      <input 
        matInput
        id="columnSearchTxt"
        placeholder="Search Columns"
        name="columnSearchTxt"
        [(ngModel)]="colSearch.title"
      />
      <button *ngIf="colSearch.title" (click)="colSearch.title = ''" mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="searchHosts()" matTooltip="Filter on hostname">
        <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Clear">close</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-form-field>
  
    <mat-slide-toggle
      *ngFor="let col of colDefs | filter: 'title':colSearch.title"
      color="primary"
      [name]="col.title"      
      [(ngModel)]="col.includeField"
      labelPosition= "before"
    >
      {{ col.title }}
    </mat-slide-toggle>
   </section>
</app-modal>
```

**modal.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, Inject, Input, TemplateRef, ViewChild, ContentChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';

export interface DialogData {
  title: string;
  text: string;
  template: TemplateRef<any>
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  template: `<button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()">{{ btnText }}</button>`,
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.scss']
})
export class ModalComponent {

  @Input() btnText: string;
  @Input() id: string;
  @Input() modalTitle: string;
  @Input() okText: string;
  @Input() name: string;
  // @ContentChild('template') template: TemplateRef<any>;
  // @ContentChild('template') template: ElementRef<any>;
  // @ViewChild('template') template: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('template') template: ElementRef;

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) { }

  openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalDialogComponent, {
      data: {
        id: this.id, 
        title: this.modalTitle, 
        text: this.okText, 
        name: this.name,
        template: this.template
      },
    });
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'modal-dialog',
  templateUrl: './modal-dialog.component.html',
})
export class ModalDialogComponent {
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModalDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: DialogData,
  ) {}

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

**modal-dialog.component.html**

```html
<section>
    <div>
        <mat-icon (click)="onNoClick()" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="close icon">close</mat-icon>
    </div>
    <h1 mat-dialog-title>{{ data.title }}</h1>
    <div mat-dialog-content>
        <!-- Want to display html elements from app-modal -->
    </div>
    <div mat-dialog-actions>
        <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">{{ data.text ? data.text : 'Ok' }}</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass HTML into Mat Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64022275/pass-html-into-mat-dialog)

Comment: Child Elements from <app-modal></app-modal> should be displayed in <modal-dialog></modal-dialog>.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. Please understand the question properly before you mark it as duplicate. If you can't understand, please give some time for others to respond or wait for one day at least.